# Named ports in Windows

Tags: windows, port

I wonder how stuff like this works in Windows (XP and other that have telnet):

```
Start-> Run -> cmd -> telnet <xyz.com> http

Start-> Run -> cmd -> telnet <xyz.com> pop3

Start-> Run -> cmd -> telnet <xyz.com> smtp
```

Are these "**named**" ports? Only Windows knows that it has to substitute port numbers because these are standard ports? Is there way I could create such a named port on windows? I would like something like this:

```
telnet <xyz.com> oracle
```

to translate to:

```
telnet <xyz.com> 1521
```

Answer (score 12):

Look at:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services
```

This is a text file containing these named ports.

Comment: See also: `getservbyname()` and `/etc/services`